# ¿Cómo puedo calcular la moda de los elementos de una lista en Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Supongamos que tengo la lista:
lista=[1, 7, 7, 7, 6, 12, 123, 1, 5]
¿Cómo se podría calcular la moda de la lista, la cuál es 7, en Python 3?

Comment: Es importante agregar lo que investigaste o trataste, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que por "capada" quieres decir que no tienes librerías tipo `numpy` que pudieran resolverte el problema, sino que tan sólo dispones de los módulos de la biblioteca estándar Python.

Pues uno de estos módulos (disponible incluso para Python2) puede ayudarte. En el módulo `collections` tienes la clase `Counter` que sirve para contar el número de veces que se repiten los elementos de una lista.

El objeto retornado por `Counter()` tiene el método `.most_comon(n)` que te devuelve una lista con los `n` elementos más comunes (más repetidos). La moda sería por tanto el primero de ellos. Cada uno de estos elementos te lo devuelve en forma de par, siendo el primer elemento del par el dato, y el segundo cuántas veces se repite.

Por tanto tu problema se resuelve así:

```
from collections import Counter

lista=[1, 7, 7, 7, 6, 12, 123, 1, 5]
moda, freq = Counter(lista).most_common(1)[0]
```

En este caso `moda` saldría 7, y `freq` saldría 3 (el número de veces que se repite el 7).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
import collections

lista = [1, 7, 7, 7, 6, 12, 123, 1, 5]

cuenta = collections.Counter(lista)

moda = cuenta.most_common(1)[0][0]

print(moda)
```